# Рисуется только один пиксель

Tags: c#

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bitmap = new Bitmap(100, 100);
    graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
    picture(sender, null);


    pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
    pictureBox1.Refresh();
}
public string picture(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) //здесь читается строка и потом рисуется пиксель
{
    string str = textBox2.Text; 

    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case '1':
                white(sender,e);
                break;
            case '0':
                black(sender,e);
                break;
        }
    }
    return str;

}
public void white(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int x = random.Next(0, 100); 
    int y = random.Next(0, 100);
    graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, x, y, 10, 10);
    graphics.Save();
}

public void black(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int x = random.Next(0, 100);
    int y = random.Next(0, 100);
    graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, x, y, 10, 10);
    graphics.Save();
}
```

Проблема в том, что в picturebox выводится только один пиксель, а должно быть несколько

Comment: А откуда, по-вашему, возьмутся другие пиксели, если вы каждый раз создаете новый битмап для рисования?

Comment: Куда переместить?

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что рисуется только один пиксель?

Comment: @АнтонРябухин переместить, например, в приватное свойство типа Bimap, и работать с ним, PictureBox, по идее должен подхватить изменения самостоятельно или рефрешнуть его принудительно.

Answer (score 0):

Код, реализующий вашу хотелку, до безобразия прост:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var text = textBox.Text;
    var bitmap = new Bitmap(text.Length, 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        switch (text[i])
        {
            case '1':
                bitmap.SetPixel(i, 0, Color.Black);
                break;
            case '0':
                bitmap.SetPixel(i, 0, Color.White);
                break;
        }
    }

    pictureBox.Image?.Dispose();
    pictureBox.Image = bitmap;
}
```

На форме имеются текстбокс, пикчабокс, кнопка.

По нажатию на кнопку берётся введённый текст, создаётся изображение высотой один пиксель и длиной равной длине текста.

Далее в цикле в битмапе закрашиваются пиксели. Координаты пикселей, которые вы получаете с плясками и бубном (зачем-то с помощью рандома) элементарны: y - всегда 0, ведь у нас изображение-полоска толщиной в один пиксель (строка-то одна), x - позиция пикселя равна позиции символа.

Всё!

Единственное, обратите внимание на вызов `Dispose` - нужно освободить ранее занятый ресурс (это критически важно; по мере набора опыта поймёте для чего это).

---

Это один из возможных способов. Пиксели также можно рисовать с помощью `Graphics`.
Можно создать изображение любой ширины (только нужно продумать, как пользователь будет вводить данные).

PS: если что, задавайте новые *вопросы* (не комментарии).